# Is there a way to have smoother curves in HighCharts JS?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display a chart. Currently the lines are very rigid and create sharp points when going up and down. Is there a way alter the configuration options to create a smoother curve, similar to the image below? [image: chart image that I'd like to replicate]

I've tried setting the type to spline, but doesn't seem to have any effect

plotOptions: { series: { type: 'spline' } }

Comment: One caution:  Is the lack of smoothness an artifact of graphing and therefore NOT reflecting reality?  It could be that the lack of smoothness IS reflecting reality?  That would make a huge difference ....

Comment: In signal processing, a low pass filter would accomplish what you are seeking, of course, there are many parameters, and see above comment also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart in the image you sent is also Highcharts.

So yes, it can be done just in a slightly different way than you tried. This can be done by setting the series type in 2 places, unfortunately this cannot be done in `plotOptions`, this property is used to set options for these individual series types.

The first way is to use [`chart.type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type) which sets the default series type:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5]
  }]
});
```

The second way is to set the type directly in a given series ([`series.type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.type)):

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    data: [2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 1]
  }]
});
```

- `chart.type` demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1khwfv0/
- `series.type` demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c4gh6tf7/

Answer (score 2):

Some individual on [the Highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37736) found a workaround for e.g. getting smoothed lines, by adding this (slightly adjusted) line:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.getPointSpline = Highcharts.seriesTypes.spline.prototype.getPointSpline;
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/mL2wt35g/).
The `getPointSpline` has the following documentation:

> Get the spline segment from a given point's previous neighbour to the given point.

It is used by the `getGraphPath` function to draw the path.

Comment: This is a workaround that simply overwrites the function responsible for drawing straight lines with the function that the spline type has. So if you don't want to lose the default functionality for the line type, just use a spline series.